# RVM, Capistrano and bundler path issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, capistrano, bundler

i seem to have a discrepancy between production's gem path when I installed manually versus  by bundler+capistrano.

After rvm installing ruby 1.9.2 and creating a gemset "myapp", i did install bundler via gem install bundler.

It was installed into the path:

> **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapp**/gems

Bundler via Capistrano installed the remaining gems into:

> **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapp/ruby/1.9.1**/gems

Beginning of my deploy.rb file is:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rails_env,             'production'
set :rvm_type,              :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapp"
set :rvm_path,              "/usr/local/rvm"
set :rvm_bin_path,      "#{rvm_path}/bin"
set :rvm_lib_path,      "#{rvm_path}/lib"

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH'                    => "#{rvm_path}/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin:#{rvm_bin_path}/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION'    => '1.9.2',
  'GEM_HOME'        => "#{rvm_path}/gems/#{rvm_ruby_string}",
  'GEM_PATH'        => "#{rvm_path}/gems/#{rvm_ruby_string}",
  'BUNDLE_PATH'     => "#{rvm_path}/gems/#{rvm_ruby_string}"
}

set :bundle_dir,            "#{rvm_path}/gems/#{rvm_ruby_string}"
set :bundle_flags,      "--deployment --verbose"
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the discrepancy?

Comment: I bolded the paths.  Bundler basically installs to my GEM_PATH+"ruby/1.9.1/gems" instead I want it to go in to my GEM_PATH alone.

Comment: Installing gems in the `ruby/1.9.1` subdirectory seems to be the norm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352262/why-does-bundler-install-gems-into-a-1-9-1-directory-when-1-9-2-is-the-only-ruby. Does this cause a problem for you (missing gems, etc)?

Comment: That norm makes sense if you aren't using RVM, but it doesn't if you are. If you're using RVM then your rubies and their version names and your gemset is already a part of your GEMPATH name why now should bundle version my gems based on ruby version! It's stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annoyingly, bundler folks have no intention on working well with RVM and want bundler to manage ruby versions so the workaround so far for me is to simply symbollically link for ruby and 1.9.1 in my GEM_PATH directory pointing to "."

Answer (score 0):

After you created your gemset, did you explicitly "rvm use 1.9.2@myapp" before installing bundler?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems with capistrano/bundler/rvm setups.

At least in my case, if I run

```
bundle exec <command>
```

from the capistrano created installation:

```
/u/apps/<app-name>/current
```

I pick up my GEMDIR

```
bundle exec env | grep GEM_HOME
GEM_HOME=/u/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
```