# Why is my gem "INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:" ...1.9.1 when the "RUBY VERSION:" is 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are gems installed in a 1.9.1 directory when my Ruby version is different than 1.9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352262/why-are-gems-installed-in-a-1-9-1-directory-when-my-ruby-version-is-different-th)

I've installed Ruby 1.9.3-p0 on an RHEL 6 system (Linux 2.6.32-122.el6.x86_64) by downloading the source and compiling. I didn't use any options. Just `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`.

When I run `gem environment` I get...

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.17
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Notice the references to "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/**1.9.1**". Shouldn't that be "**1.9.3**"?

I ran `gem update --system`, and it output "1.9.1" both before and after I did so.

Comment: Summary: Standard library hasn't moved, so default Ruby path still includes 1.9.1.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder/8565831#8565831

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. I have Ruby 1.9.2, and the directory is still 1.9.1. I think this is for backward compatibly with gems from previous minor versions.