# Bitnami GitLab 5.2.0: gitlab_sidekiq not running and could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, service, gitlab, bitnami

We are using [Bitnami GitLab 5.2.0](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/README.txt).
We stumbled upon that we can't push into new repository, like

`git@192.168.133.10:sandbox/testgit2.git`,

but we can work with old ones. Closer investigation showed that gitlab_sidekiq is not running.

`/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart gitlab_sidekiq`

**gitlab_sidekiq could not be started**

Where to look? Should I [update](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/update) first?

UPDATE: Bitnami GitLab 5.2 server is broken down: can't push code into new repositories.
(While old repositories are unaffected)

```
TestProject4>git remote add origin git
@192.168.133.10:sandbox/testproject4.git

TestProject4>git push -u origin master

fatal: '/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/repositories/sandbox/testproject4.git' does not  appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

UPDATE WITH ANSWERS:

I am using virtual machine in VirtualBox on my PC (in 1 team as pilot moving the VM to some VM host)
Yes, I modified gitlab.yml

/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/log/sidekiq.log has this lines in repetition, so they should give clue (look like some thing wrong when reading some file)

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/environment.rb:5)
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 73 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.8/lib/settingslogic.rb:113:in `initialize'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.8/lib/settingslogic.rb:71:in `new'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.8/lib/settingslogic.rb:71:in `instance'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/settingslogic-2.0.8/lib/settingslogic.rb:48:in `[]'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:199:in `boot_system'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:47:in `parse'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.8.0/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
    from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

[GitLab says it requires ruby 1.9.3](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/5-2-stable#requirements), but here I see 1.9.1. Can that be problem?

Comment: Hi Paul, did you finally found the problem?

Comment: gitlab.yml should be the reason, as it is the only file I changed in latest weeks (trying to make LDAP work). I can't see any problem with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825404/how-to-check-yml-grammar-is-correct-gitlab-yml , and right now I can't find what GitLab has for checking installation is OK. (I ran it once, but it gave me only errors)

Answer (score 2):

It is strange. What are you using, the installer, the virtual machine or the cloud image? If the sidekiq server is not running it is possible that the repository was not created properly. Could you check if there is any error in the sidekiq log file?

/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/logs/sidekiq.log

Did you modify any configuration file for GitLab?

EDITED:

The problem seems a wrong configuration in the gitlab.yml. It is also important the white spaces. Could you check your change in that file?

/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 73 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)

GitLab CI ships Ruby 1.9.3 latest stable version. The folder name uses 1.9.1 for backguard compatibility [Why is my gem "INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:" ...1.9.1 when the "RUBY VERSION:" is 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406263/why-is-my-gem-installation-directory-1-9-1-when-the-ruby-version-is-1-9)

Please post the gitlab.yml file if you do not find the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `<tab>` in my yml file.

It's quite strange error though!