# Bitnami GitLab 5.2 server is down: We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)

Tags: linux, git, service, gitlab, bitnami

Bitnami GitLab 5.2 server is down with messages

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

I was not notified! Yesterday I just could create new, not it s all inaccessible.

Current services status:

- apache already running
- gitlab_sidekiq not running ([Bitnami GitLab 5.2.0: gitlab_sidekiq not running and could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690321/bitnami-gitlab-5-2-0-gitlab-sidekiq-not-running-and-could-not-be-started))
- gitlabci_sidekiq already running
- redis already running
- mysql already running

After `reboot`, it is still the same.

- main page "Congratulations!" can be seen,
- gitlab app - We're sorry,
- GitLab CI- OK

UPDATE WITH ANSWERS:

VM with 512MB, 1 CPU core

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the BitNami GitLab virtual machine? How much RAM did you configured for it? GitLab requires some resources in the machine, try to check the Sidekiq log file to see if there is any error: /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/logs/sidekiq.log

Comment: I think this question depends on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690321/bitnami-gitlab-5-2-0-gitlab-sidekiq-not-running-and-could-not-be-started which should be solved first.