# two different versions of ruby referenced in error message?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are gems installed in a 1.9.1 directory when my Ruby version is different than 1.9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352262/why-are-gems-installed-in-a-1-9-1-directory-when-my-ruby-version-is-different-th)

I got the following error message in my console. I fixed the error, but there was something about it that I didn't understand, namely the meaning of the difference between 1.9.3 and 1.9.1.

```
.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
```

The system wide version of ruby has been set to 1.9.3 using rbenv, however, that was only done recently, and I'm wondering if this particular app was made with 1.9.1. Is that what `site_ruby/1.9.1` refers to?

Second question, I know that I can check the current version of ruby in the system using `ruby -v` but how do you find out what version of ruby a project was made with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because 1.9.1 is the Ruby C API version, which allows gems in that directory to be used across Ruby versions which comply with the same Ruby C API version (1.9.1–1.9.3 all use 1.9.1) without needing to recompile C extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The subdirectories for gems and site_ruby haven't changed since `1.9.1`.