# How to set RUBY EXECUTABLE in .gemrc

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, environment-variables

My `~.gemrc` looks like:

```
gem: --user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc
gemhome: /home/me/.gems
gempath:
  - /home/me/.gems
```

and `gem env` returns:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-05-14 patchlevel 547) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/me/.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/me/.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/me/.gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/me/.gems"
     - "gempath" => ["/home/me/.gems"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

My `$PATH` is

```
/home/me/ruby:/home/me/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

and `which ruby` returns `/home/slackbot/ruby/ruby`.

Moreover when I install any gem like `gem install bundler` it goes to

```
.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle
```

regardless my `1.9.3` version.

What am I doing wrong to set it up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are gems installed in a 1.9.1 directory when my Ruby version is different than 1.9.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352262/why-are-gems-installed-in-a-1-9-1-directory-when-my-ruby-version-is-different-th)

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem with `RUBY EXECUTABLE`

Comment: The `RUBY EXECUTABLE` shown in the `gem env` output will always be the path of the ruby interpreter which is used to run the `gem env` command (which here might use the first `ruby` executable found in your `PATH`. But it says nothing about your `PATH` or any other system configuration. Generally, it seems you have multiple ruby installations in various places on your system which overlay each other. You should fix that to prevent inconsistencies and strange, hard to debug errors.

Comment: (Also, if you sanitize the shown output and paths, do it consistently everywhere, or preferably, just don't do it as it makes our work helping you much more difficult)

Comment: @HolgerJust, many thanks for comprehensive explanation! What if I want to have different ruby per user without touching default root ruby?

Comment: @squixy: Look at [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).